# Can Joe Diamond attempt to solve a puzzle twice with his magnifying glass?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

In our latest session of Mansions of Madness, we allowed Joe Diamond to use his magnifying glass to make two attempts at a rune puzzle. However, at the time and shortly after the completion of the game, we questioned whether this should be allowed.

I came across [this answer](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/658531/joe-diamonds-magnfying-glass) on the Geek stating that "a single investigator may not attempt the same puzzle more than once in a turn," but since it doesn't reference any specific rule I just wanted to find out whether this is the general consensus.

The Magnifying Glass card reads:

> Once per turn, immediately after you spend an action to explore a room, you may take 1 additional action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**One puzzle attempt per turn per investigator is the rule.**

From the [rules](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/mansions-of-madness/support/MansionsOfMadnessLoRes.pdf), bottom of the first column on page 18 -

> Each investigator can only attempt the same puzzle once per turn
>   (but multiple investigators may attempt the same puzzle on the
>   same turn).